# Pegar activity atual e colocar em outra activity

Tags: android

Meu app tem uma activity que é uma lista de clientes e também uma activity de vendas. Quando eu clico somente em um nome na lista de cliente ele abre os detalhes do cliente. Lá tem todos os dados do cliente. Até aqui tudo certo. Mas quando vou na activity de vendas preciso selecionar o cliente para fazer a venda. Acontece que quando clico no cliente gostaria de selecionar apenas ele e trazer para a activity de vendas. Mas quando clico ele abre a tela de detalhes de clientes.

[image: Listview Clientes]
[image: Cadastro de Produto]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro passar um parâmetro para a activity de clientes, para saber qual determinada ação, por exemplo...

Chamada para detalhes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityClientes.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("MODO_TELA", ActivityClientes.MODO_DETALHES);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Chamada para selecionar o cliente:

```
private static final int IDENTIFICADOR_EXEMPLO = 0;

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityClientes.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("MODO_TELA", ActivityClientes.MODO_SELECIONAR);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, IDENTIFICADOR_EXEMPLO);
```

na mesma activity implementar:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == IDENTIFICADOR_EXEMPLO) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Integer mIdSelect = data.getIntExtra("IdCliente", 0);
        //aqui você já tem o idSelecionado 
    }
  }
}
```

e na sua Activity do cliente, tratar o "modo atual" por exemplo:

```
public class ActivityClientes extends Activity{

   public static final int MODO_DETALHES = 0;
   public static final int MODO_SELECIONAR = 1;

   private int mModoAtual = -1;

   ....
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
         if (extras.containsKey("MODO_TELA")) {
             mModoAtual = extras.getInt("MODO_TELA", -1);


    //você tera o "ModoAtual para usar na sua activity para tratar"
    //exemplo:

    if (mModoAtual == MODO_DETALHES){
      //código
    }

   }



   //quando quiser usar o activityForResult, seta o result antes de fechar a tela
   private void exemplo(){

    if (mModoAtual == MODO_SELECIONAR){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("IdCliente", 5);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }

   }


  //por exemplo no onclick do item da sua listview, faça algo parecido com isso.
   public void OnClick(..){

    if (mModoAtual == MODO_DETALHES){
      //abrir detalhes
    }
    else if (mModoAtual == MODO_SELECIONAR){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("IdCliente", idClienteSelecionado);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: Eai Marco. Cara quando coloco esse código na minha activity principal bundle.putInt("MODO_TELA", ActivityClientes.MODO_DETALHES); o putInt dá erro. E não tem nenhuma opção para resolver. Sabes o que possa ser ?

Comment: @ArturMafezzoliJúnior, você na sua Activity colocou a constante MODO_DETALHES? Você pode tentar substituir por um valor fixo para testar, por exemplo bundle.putInt("MODO_TELA", 0)

Comment: tem como abrir o chat por aqui. Porque ainda tenho dúvidas. =(

Comment: Vou ver como faz para abrir o chat

Comment: É só entrar [aqui](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45809/android-activitys-bundle)